# Background color to fill top 70px of div behind text

Tags: html, css

Is there an easier way of doing this. I just want the background color to fill the top width of the div, 70px high and the entire width of the div, in this case 400px. I was able to hack out a solution but it looks ugly. Sorry I'm using inline styles since I cannot easily add new CSS to a 6,500 page website.

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #bbb;  padding:20px; width:400px; height:150px; float:left; margin-right:60px;">
    <div style="background:#cccccc; width:440px; height:40px; padding:0; position:relative; margin-left:-20px; margin-top:-20px;"></div>
    <div style="background:#cccccc; width:420px; height:30px; padding-left:20px; position:relative; margin-left:-20px; margin-top:-20px;">
        <p><b>To learn more:</b></p>
    </div>
    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Contact a sales rep</a></p>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DivineChef/827a91fu/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `linear-gradient`.

```
background: #eeeeee; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%, #eeeeee 70px, #ffffff 70px, #ffffff 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#eeeeee), color-stop(70px,#eeeeee), color-stop(70px,#ffffff), color-stop(100%,#ffffff)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#eeeeee 70px,#ffffff 70px,#ffffff 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#eeeeee 70px,#ffffff 70px,#ffffff 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#eeeeee 70px,#ffffff 70px,#ffffff 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #eeeeee 0%,#eeeeee 70px,#ffffff 70px,#ffffff 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#ffffff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Codes generated by http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/